# C# SKYPE4COMLib Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, skype, skype4com

I'm making SkypeBot and I want respond also to Facebook messages. I'm using SKYPE4COMLib. But it works only for skype protocol.

```
skype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(skype_MessageStatus);

// in event
skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, message);
```

Or can I make it simply by SkypeKitNET?

Thanks for responds.

Comment: I think skype4comlib is older than skype which had integration with facebook, so I guess it doesn't have that feature.

Comment: So how can I do that? Can I do it "simply" by SkypeKit or are there any other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

if the Facebook account has been tied to the Skype account then Facebook messages are received in the Skype client the same as other messages and these can be addressed in the same way as normal Skype messages.

Its worth noting that server implimentations of the desktop API are likely prohibited int the Skype terms of use.

SkypeKit specifically prohibits any server implimentations in the licence agreement

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Facebook lib then.
For example: http://csharpsdk.org/
Just can run these two at the same time.

Comment: How can I catch Facebook messages which are recieved by Skype client by using this lib?

Answer (score 0):

I used XMPP library agsXMPP SDK for .NET C#
Thanks for responds.